# Pandas: apply a function with 2 array as input and return a single value

Tags: python, pandas, hierarchical

I have a pandas DataFrame with hierarchical column names like this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1542)

dates = pd.date_range('29/01/17', periods = 6)

pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,6), index = dates,\
             columns = [['g1', 'g1', 'g1', 'g2', 'g2', 'g2'],\
                        ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3']])
```

And I want to apply a function that, for each group in the first level of columns, takes the columns 'c2' and 'c3' and returns a single value.

An example of the function (that in the real case is more complex) can be

```
def function(first_column, second_column):
    return(max(first_column) - max(second_column))
```

When I apply it to my DataFrame I want to have back a DataFrame that tells me the output of 'function' for each group, so, in this case, just 2 numbers for 'g1' and 'g2'.

**Note that I want it to works also in case of gorupby()** so that, in this case, I get the result of the function for each group ('g1' and 'g2') and for each groupby subset.

For the case above, if I want to aggregate by month, the result should be:

```
         g1      g2                    
1  0.909464     1.638375
2  0.698515     0.33819
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to jezrael for your useful input. Builiding up on it, I've written a solution to the problem: apply a complex function that takes two or more arrays as input and return a single value and apply it to a dataframe with hierarchical column names together with resample based on datetime indexing.

First, here is the table that I will use for the example

```
mat = np.random.randint(0, 101, size = (10, 6))

index = pd.date_range(start = '25 Jan 2018', periods = 10)

first_column_name = ['Group1']*3 + ['Group2']*3
second_column_name = ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3']*2

df = pd.DataFrame(mat, index = index, columns = [first_column_name,\
                                                 second_column_name])

           Group1           Group2          
             Col1 Col2 Col3   Col1 Col2 Col3
2018-01-25     11   36   80     88   31   33
2018-01-26     30   32   61     53   55   43
2018-01-27     64   26   21     63   33   93
2018-01-28     52   59   23     54   91   60
2018-01-29     93   88   27     16   88    7
2018-01-30     28   76   48      5   38    1
2018-01-31      7   29   45     86   53   96
2018-02-01     18   89   69      3   34   34
2018-02-02      0    7   94     99    5   68
2018-02-03     29   13   98     25   51   44
```

Now I want to apply the function:

```
def my_fun(arr1, arr2):

    arr1 = np.array(arr1)
    arr2 = np.array(arr2)
    tmp = np.abs(arr1 - arr2)
    return(np.sum(tmp))
```

Note that this is a simple case: in the real case the function is extremely more complex and work-around can't be taken!

The desired output is the following, when I apply the function to 'Col1' 'Col 3':

```
            Group1  Group2
2018-01-31     296     124
2018-02-28     214      81
```

To do that I've applied a little bit of object oriented programming to combine resample with groupby.

So I created this class

```
class ApplyFunction():

    def __init__(self, column_names, fun, resample = None):
        self.cn = column_names
        self.fun  = fun
        self.resample = resample

        # Initialize the stored values
        self.stored_values = dict()
        for name in self.cn:
            self.stored_values[name] = []

    def __store(self, x):
        self.stored_values[self.to_store].append(x.values.copy())

    def wrapper_with_resample(self, x):

        if self.resample is None:
            print('Can not use this function with resample = None')
            return np.nan

        # Get the names of the group
        group_name = x.columns.levels[0][x.columns.labels[0][0]]

        # Get the time-steps output of resample (doing a dumm operation)
        self.timesteps = x.resample(self.resample).apply(lambda x : len(x)).index

        # Store the resampled variables
        for name in self.cn:
            self.to_store = name
            x[(group_name, name)].resample(self.resample).apply(self.__store)

        # Create a new DataFrame for the output
        out = []
        for i in range(len(self.timesteps)):
            out.append(self.fun(*[self.stored_values[name][i] for name in self.cn]))
        out = pd.Series(out, index = self.timesteps)

        # Reset self.stored_values
        for name in self.cn:
            self.stored_values[name] = []        
        return out
```

And then I use it as follows:

```
f = ApplyFunction(column_names = ['Col1', 'Col3'], fun = my_fun, resample = 'M')

output = df.groupby(level = 0, axis = 1).apply(f.wrapper_with_resample)
```

This solution has been done because here we want to apply together groupby and resample and I haven't found a suitable solution in pandas.

I hope this solution is useful for someone; of course there is room for improvement so feel free to post alternative and more efficient solutions!

Thanks. Marco

Comment: @Marco - I think your answer is what you need, but how I can create it with your sample data? It is impossible. But it is up to  you. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by first level of `MultiIndex` with custom function with [`xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) for select second level of `MultiIndex`:

```
np.random.seed(1542)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,6), index = range(6),\
             columns = [['g1', 'g1', 'g1', 'g2', 'g2', 'g2'],\
                        ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3']])
print (df)
         g1                            g2                    
         c1        c2        c3        c1        c2        c3
0 -0.556376 -0.295627  0.618673 -0.409434  0.107020 -1.143460
1 -0.145909  0.017417  0.117667 -0.301128  0.880918 -1.027282
2  2.287448  1.528137 -1.528636  0.052728 -1.842634 -0.757457
3 -0.651587 -1.075176  1.128277  0.632036 -0.240965  0.421812
4 -1.620718  0.146108  0.030500 -0.446294 -0.206774  0.819859
5 -0.757296  1.826793 -0.352837 -2.048026  1.362865  1.024671

def f(x):
    a = x.xs('c2', axis=1, level=1)[x.name].max()
    b = x.xs('c3', axis=1, level=1)[x.name].max()
    #print (a)
    return a - b

s = df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).apply(f)
print (s)
g1    0.698516
g2    0.338194
dtype: float64
```

Similar solution:

```
def f(x):
    a = x.xs('c2', axis=1, level=1).squeeze()
    b = x.xs('c3', axis=1, level=1).squeeze()
    return a.max() - b.max()

a = df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).apply(f)
print (a)
g1    0.698516
g2    0.338194
dtype: float64
```

EDIT:

```
def f(x):
    a = x.xs('c2', axis=1, level=1)[x.name]
    b = x.xs('c3', axis=1, level=1)[x.name]
    #print (a)
    return a - b

s = df.resample('M').max().groupby(level=0, axis=1).apply(f)
print (s)
                  g1        g2
2017-01-31  0.909464  1.638375
2017-02-28  0.698516  0.338194

print (df.resample('M').max())
                  g1                            g2                    
                  c1        c2        c3        c1        c2        c3
2017-01-31  2.287448  1.528137  0.618673  0.052728  0.880918 -0.757457
2017-02-28 -0.651587  1.826793  1.128277  0.632036  1.362865  1.024671
```

EDIT1:

Solution should be simplify more:

```
a = df.resample('M').max()
b = a.xs('c2', axis=1, level=1)
c = a.xs('c3', axis=1, level=1)
d = b - c
print (d)
                  g1        g2
2017-01-31  0.909464  1.638375
2017-02-28  0.698516  0.338194
```

Comment: Ok. This works. What if now I want to groupby on the rows? I.E. the index column is a DatetimeIndex and I want to group by the months so, for each month I have the output for g1 and g2..

Comment: @Dalmo1991 - Not sure if understand, can you modify your question with new DataFrame and expected output? Thanks.

Comment: @jazrael I've changed my question. Thanks

Comment: @Dalmo1991 - You need `resample` first for max per months and then a bit modified first solution. Please check edited answer.